# Regexp: How to find sequence from which find range of characters but stop if sequence is found?

Tags: regex, replace, find, match

I have a broken CSS file full of characters and broken `color: #{hexval};` properties.

I want to retrieve hexadecimal values. Technically, I want to:

- Find pattern ( 'color#' + 6 characters ).
- From found pattern, check if up to 3 last characters are in order 'c', 'o' or 'l', in which case found pattern changes ( 'color#' + 3 characters ) [so it does not overlap another 'color#' sequence].
- Remove anything but found pattern and found pattern's 'color#'.

I've been tinkering with Regex101(https://regex101.com/) and Google for an hour now, having only been able to get these:

- `/(?:color#+.....)\w/g`
- `/(?:color#+.....+?(?=color))\w/g`

[Yep, believe it or not, I wrote these shameful horrors all by myself, and am very proud of it.]

The problems are that:

- `/(?:color#+.....)\w/g` kind of works at the start but breaks later in the string.
- `/(?:color#+.....+?(?=color#))\w/g` seems better at the start but breaks a different way later in the string.

… And I have no idea of why or how, so I'm stuck at the 'find matching pattern' part. I first tried something with substitution but it did not work and I lost what I did.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**`color.txt` file sample**

ccolor#969896c1color#0086b3eecolor#795da31color#333ecolor#63a35ccolor#a71d5dde1cceeacolor#183691color#ed6a43dcolor#b52a1dcolor#f8f8f8color#b52a1drccecolor#63a35clcolor#693a17ecolor#1d3e81color#008080ccolor#333bcolor#333dcolor#bd2c00color#ffecec1color#55a532color#eaffeadrcolor#795da3ocolor#1d3e81er#ffffffcolor#999999r1#e8e8e8blcolor#ffffffcolor#333333crorcolor#000000erlayer#c8c8fal0030#ffffff2erlayere#c6

**Example of results:**

[Regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kR1fF0/1)

c**color#969896**c1color#0086b3eecolor#795da31color#333ecolor#63a35ccolor#a71d5dde1cceeacolor#183691color#ed6a43dcolor#b52a1dcolor#f8f8f8color#b52a1drccecolor#63a35clcolor#693a17ecolor#1d3e81color#008080ccolor#333bcolor#333dcolor#bd2c00color#ffecec1color#55a532color#eaffeadrcolor#795da3ocolor#1d3e81er#ffffffcolor#999999r1#e8e8e8blcolor#fff**fffcolor#333**333crorcolor#000000erlayer#c8c8fal0030#ffffff2erlayere#c6

**Edit:** As Wiktor Stribiżew and Maria Deleva also found, the problem was that when a sequence ended like `color#fff` and followed by parasite text (eg 'ab') then another `color#`'s 'c', the regex didn't 'recognize' an hexadecimal triplet. [Still, apart from adding an exception (such as 'if the hexadecimal value's 3 first characters are the same and the last character is 'c', only consider the 3 first characters), I don't see how to detect parasited sequences.]

Comment: Please share the input text as text, inside the question. What about [`color#\w{6}`](https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/1)? Or a more specific [`/color#[a-f0-9]{6}/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Which input? The text file's content or what the regex finds? If you mean what the regex finds, it is inside the screenshot [I will now edit my post to put it, too]. About your regex, the problem is that it breaks after a while [it first finds stuff like 'color#969896' but starts finding stuff like '43eyaecolor#' later in the string].

Comment: No one cannot test regex against an image, you know, a tiny percent of SO users will ever want to work as an OCR software.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it's a bit complicated to insert this in the post. I will put emphasis on what it does, I hope it'll be clear.

Comment: You can also save the regex101 page by clicking the save icon on the left bar (next to the regular expression box). It provides you with a link and all the information is there (including the text). Just as a side note.

Comment: @MariaDeleva I didn't even notice that, thank you! I'm adding it to the original post, too. https://regex101.com/r/kR1fF0/1

Comment: Please re-check my first comment suggestion, regex101.com has issues with correct highlighting of matches. I wrapped the pattern with a capturing group, see https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/4 and the *MATCH INFORMATION* pane on the right. Does it show correct matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, thanks a lot. At some point in my early attempts (the lost ones), I wondered if it wasn't due to bugs these kind of web-based services are often subject to. My first solution looked like yours but much more complicated, probably for nothing. Yours does work indeed, but I still have to find how to stop it from considering another found 'color#' sequence start as part of the current sequence.

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Is it JavaScript?

Comment: No, I will use it in VIm. I didn't write the right problem on my previous comment, I will comment your answer to point the second problem. Still, your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: I guess in Vim, you need to escape the parentheses, or use "very magic mode". If you want to replace all the texts other than the codes, you might try `:%s/\v.*?color#([a-z0-9]{6})/\1\n/g`

Comment: It is difficult to provide you with a final solution because your question sounds rather unclear as for what your final result should look like. Check what an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, you do not have to provide the whole testing text, just its representative part for us to repro your issue. Expected behavior with a sample input/output is always welcome. Without that, my answer, as you see, has many alternatives and hints on what you can do more with the pattern, and most probably, you are not interested in 75% of the answer.

Comment: In VIm, I actually might need to escape some characters.

Comment: Consider my problem solved by you two's answers.  [I don't see how to distinguish whether a `color#{hexval}` sequence is parasited (eg `color#fffabc`, where 'ab' are parasite characters and 'c' a next `color#` sequence's first character) or not (eg `color#fffabc`, where the sequence actually looks like a parasited one but isn't). Regexp alone won't suffice, it would take detection algorithms or AI for such a precise task.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to retrieve the hex values (6 `[a-zA-Z0-9]` chars) after `color#`.

You can use

```
/color#([a-z0-9]{6})/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/4), the value you need is inside Group 1.

The regex matches:

- `color#` - a literal `color#` string
- `([a-z0-9]{6})` - Group 1 capturing 6 (due to the limiting quantifier `{6}`) characters that are inside `a-z`, `A-Z` (as the case insensitive modifier `/i` is used) or `0-9`.

Or to match both 6- and 3-char hex values:

```
/color#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?))/gi
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/8).

**Explanation**:

- `color#` - a literal substrin `color#`
- `([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?))` - Group 1 capturing either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `[a-f0-9]{6}` - 6 hex chars (`a-z`, `A-Z` letters or `0-9` digits)
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?)` - 3 hex chars that are  not followed with `c`, or `co` or `col`.

Comment: Thank you! This works, now I have another problem. Since 'color''s 'o' isn't part of the `a-z` range, another 'color#' sequence won't be a problem until the 6th character after the '#' is a 'c'. As I said, the CSS file is broken — there are characters from the `a-z` sequence that weren't part of the `{color: #{hexval};}` sequences but of external sequences [like `abc{color: #fff;}`]. It can be seen in the 500th match in the original file ('[40487-40499] `color#aaa231`'). […]

Comment: By the time I wrote my first comment, @MariaDeleva pointed out the second problem! Thank you!

Comment: @kvpb Please do not discuss this in the comments here. Think of what you need, illustrate it in the question.

Comment: Please remove the details from these comments above to the appropriate places (to the question, and new answer).

Comment: Check [`color#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?))`](https://regex101.com/r/dG7zO8/8), too.

Comment: Both your `color#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?))` and @MariaDeleva's `(color#(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{6}(?!olor))|(?:[a-f0-9]{3})))` work great, many thanks to you two.  I'll upvote you both when I'll be allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
(color#(?:[a-f0-9]{6}(?!olor)|[a-f0-9]{3}))
```

Online demo
https://regex101.com/r/kR1fF0/4

Basically, I will discard the match if it is followed by olor (i.e., if it accidentally absorbed the c from color) and if it can't match all 6, it will try to match 3 characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to write at first. 

Comment: `color#(?:[a-f0-9]{6}(?!olor)|[a-f0-9]{3})` is cleaner

Comment: Both your `(color#(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{6}(?!olor))|(?:[a-f0-9]{3})))` and @WiktorStribiżew's `color#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}(?!c(?:ol?)?))` work great, many thanks to you two.  I'll upvote you both when I'll be allowed to.